# prove/disprove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$

Tags: limits, analysis, examples-counterexamples

For $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ s. t. $n\ge 2$,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left\{f(x)+f(nx)\right\}=0$$

Prove/disprove :

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$$

---

**My Attempt**

I think this is false because :

There is a case that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\neq 0 $ for some fixed $n$.

For example, Let $n=2$.

If

$$f(x) = (-1)^{\lfloor\log_2|x|\rfloor} $$

Then $f$ satisfies $f(x)+f(2x) = 0$ so $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\left\{f(x)+f(2x)\right\}=0$

but $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\neq 0$

So I think there is a counterexample which consist of sum of this example (with some manipulation)

How can I construct a counterexample? (or how can I prove if this is true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2f(x)=(f(x)+f(2x))+(f(x)+f(4x))-(f(2x)+f(4x))$$
Therefore $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$.

Comment: +1. Nice answer!